# StringLength from DataAnnotations not working:Win app .net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to develop a MVC win app in C# (same as web but using forms for present views). I started database first and then generated model from db which I think it is a bit lazy but my problem is something else.

I have a class like this:

```
public partial class Service
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="وارد کردن شماره ترمینال  الزامی است")]
    [MaxLength(3, ErrorMessage = "شماره ترمینال نمیتواند بیش از 3 کاراکتر باشد")]
    public long Terminal { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "وارد کردن شماره پورت الزامی است")]
    [MaxLength(5, ErrorMessage = "شماره پورت نمیتواند بیش 5 رقم باشد")]
    public long PortNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "نام رابط نمیتواند بیش از 32 کاراکتر باشد")]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "شماره تماس رابط نمیتواند بیش از 10 رقم باشد")]
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And I am calling the validations like this:

```
private List<ValidationResult> validateService(Service input)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var context = new ValidationContext(input, null, null);
        Validator.TryValidateObject(input, context, results);

        return results;
    }
```

But the result list doesn't contain any error.Example of input like this:

```
Service s = new Service();
            s.ContactName = "hasan";
            s.Terminal = 1234567;
            s.ContactNumber = "100000000000000";
```

Am I doing something wrong in calling or using incorrect DataAnnotations? Also the [MaxLength] not working for any `long` type property.